# Does caching has to be manually disabled for ajaxified forms?

Tags: forms, ajax, 8

I switched on caching on my dev environment and it looks like ajaxified forms won't work* unless I specifically set max-age to them to 0. Is this normal? Or is this the case only when a form is displayed via lazy builder?

*they will work but submitting them will result in normal behavior where the form is submitted and the page is reloaded.

Comment: If this is normal why can't Drupal do this automatically by detecting presence of #ajax configuration in the form array and setting max-age=0 on its own?

Comment: IIRC, there is an issue about this.  Wim and/or Tim would know if you can catch them in IRC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was caused by the page_cache module. It caches everything and I had wrong impression of how page_cache and dynamic_page_cache are working. I have disabled the page_cache module because I have some dynamic code that varies by the visitor so I cannot cache everything for anonymous users.

Comment: You really want to avoid disabling page cache. If you have specific pages that can't be cache, that's fine, there's an API to disable it there: "\Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger();"

Comment: @Berdir I have a block(visible on all pages) and a form(rendered as computed fields on an entity and that entity can be displayed in various pages, not just on its own page) that varies by visitor(not user! and the identification is done via cookie). And so since lazy builders will get cached via page_cache as well there is no other way for me that I see at this point.

Comment: @Berdir I have enabled page_cache and I have altered the DefaultRequestPolicy so it won't get involved if additional conditions are met. Unfortunately the forms wont use ajax submit, they will get submitted as normal forms. Also this happens with dynamic_page_cache as well. My forms are displayed as entity field and use lazy builder/post cache render method.

Comment: It looks like this issue occurres only on entity page, not when i am listing multiple entities on a single page(also via lazy builder)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by "ajaxified". That sounds like a regular form is automatically "ajaxified".

Potentially this form is violating the principle that GET forms should not manipulate state. i.e. GET forms must be stateless. HTTP dictates this, but in Drupal 7 it was not respected. In Drupal 8 it is.

See https://www.drupal.org/node/2502785.